# Unable to Append FOR UPDATE to the criteria propel

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, propel

i have a need to convert the mysql query to propel criteria,

```
$subSelect = " SELECT * FROM " . NotificationqueuePeer::TABLE_NAME . 
                 " where " . NotificationqueuePeer::ITNOTIFICATIONQUEUESTATUS . " = " . Notificationqueue :: STATUS_UNSENT . 
                 " OR " . NotificationqueuePeer::ITNOTIFICATIONQUEUESTATUS . " = " . Notificationqueue :: STATUS_TRIED . 
                 " LIMIT 5 FOR UPDATE ";
```

I Tried to convert the above SQL to propel like

```
$crit= new Criteria();

        $crit->add(NotificationqueuePeer::ITNOTIFICATIONQUEUESTATUS, Notificationqueue :: STATUS_UNSENT);
        $crit->addOr(NotificationqueuePeer::ITNOTIFICATIONQUEUESTATUS, Notificationqueue :: STATUS_TRIED);
        $crit->setLimit(5);
        $crit->add(' FOR UPDATE ', Criteria::CUSTOM);

        $notifications = NotificationqueuePeer::doSelectRS($crit);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($notifications);
```

When i printed, the Query was :

```
SELECT column1, column2,...,  FOR UPDATE  WHERE  AND (NOTIFICATIONQUEUE.ITNOTIFICATIONQUEUESTATUS=1
OR NOTIFICATIONQUEUE.ITNOTIFICATIONQUEUESTATUS=3) LIMIT 5
```

As you can notice, the **FOR UPDATE** is in wrong place, it should be appended at the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of Propel/Symfony1 this is but I can answer with regards to Symfony 1.0.

The first argument `Criteria::add()` is always assumed to be a column which is why `FOR UPDATE` seems to appear in your select column list.  I don't think there is any way to use `Criteria::add()` to append `FOR UPDATE` to the end of your query.  Propel will build the query out of each provided component (joins, wheres, orders, etc) in a very specific order which is always going to end with the LIMIT and then OFFSET clauses, if any.

It's going to be a lot simpler to either use pure SQL or build the rest of the query using Criteria, get the resultant SQL with `NotificationqueuePeer::createSelectSql($crit)` (if this is indeed Symfony 1.0 / Propel 1.2) and then append your additional piece to the result.  Either way you still need to execute it and populate the result set yourself.

If you want to see exactly what's happening and why it's a worthwhile exercise to dive into the Propel code (it's relatively straightforward) and see how `doSelectRS` actually works.